# Need To Change The Date Format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

I need to change the date format in the A Column, where I need to get something like **JULY 21 2020**
but what I'm getting on the email body is something like this *DATE - Thu Jul 23 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)*

Can you help me to change date format in the below script

```js
function sendEmail(e) {
    var thisSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (thisSheet.getName() !== 'ARTWORK' || e.range.columnStart !== 5 || e.range.rowStart == 1 || e.value !== 'NO-Materials') return;
    var body, headers = thisSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 3).getValues()[0],
        thisRow = thisSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 2, 3).getValues()[0],
        ref = thisRow[1]


    recipients = "email@email.com",
        subject = "⚫ Art Work No-Images ► " + ref,
        body = "Require Vehicle images for Social Media Campaign\n\n",
        i = 0;
    while (i < 3) {
        body += headers[i] + ' - ' + thisRow[i] + '\n';
        i++;
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body, { name: "AutoDirect" });
}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the type of the date field?

Comment: @Christiaan Date field is in A Column in the format JULY 21 2020  but When the email is triggered the date field in the email body is something like this DATE - Thu Jul 23 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `getValues()` on cells with dates will return JavaScript `Date` objects. That's the behaviour you're getting. To get the dates formatted as you want, you have two options, depending on whether you want to get the displayed format or apply different one:

## Use getDisplayValues:

The method [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) returns the values with the exact same format as in the spreadsheet. Use this instead of `getValues()` if you want to retrieve the dates with the same format as they are displayed:

> Returns a two-dimensional array of displayed values, indexed by row, then by column. The values are `String` objects. The displayed value takes into account date, time and currency formatting, including formats applied automatically by the spreadsheet's locale setting.

## Use formatDate:

If you want to apply a format that is different than the one displayed on the spreadsheet, you can keep using `getValues()` and then format the returned date values with [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) according to [this specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). For example:

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimezone(), "MMMM d yyyy");
```

Comment: @lamblichus Im not coder, but what I understood as per your explanation, the code has to change like this? 
`'thisRow = thisSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 2, 3).getValues()[Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimezone(), "MMMM d yyyy")];`

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil No. If you want to keep format, you should just replace `getValues()` with `getDisplayValues()`.

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil Not sure where you have the dates you want to format, but if you replace both instances of `getValues()` by `getDisplayValues()`, it should work for you. Let me know if that's the case or you need more pointers.

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil For example, if the dates an on `thisRow`, you should replace this: `thisRow = thisSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 2, 3).getValues()[0]` with this `thisRow = thisSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 2, 3).getDisplayValues()[0]`. There is no need to use the second method (`Utilities.formatDate`) if you want to keep the format. I wrote two different options, they are not to be combined.

Comment: @lamblichus I've added a screenshot of my worksheet for better understanding. Can you have a look at it?

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil Have you tried the change I proposed in my last comment? Do you want to keep the formatting or apply another one?

Comment: @lamblichus it works like charm. :) I got it and learned a new coding format. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218270/discussion-between-muhammed-aadhil-and-iamblichus).